# Which expression is more polite? Could you or can you?

Tags: speech

If I can't find something in a grocery, which question is more polite? "Could you tell me where I can find the mouthwash?" or "Can you tell me where I can find the mouthwash?"  And I'm not sure "Could you tell me ...." is a common expression for asking or needing help.

Comment: "Could you..." seems more polite, but I would phrase it differently. "Excuse me please, where can I find the mouthwash?" which is what you want to know above their abilities.

Comment: "Could you..." is a more polite way of asking "Can you..."  "Can you..." isn't innately impolite, but "Could you..." is significantly more polite.  There's no need to change the phrasing.  "Could you tell me where I can find the mouthwash?" is expressed exactly as many, many native speakers would.  Some might throw a "please" between "you" and "tell," especially when trying to be polite, but not necessarily.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I rephrased it, because an unhelpful person might reply "yes" or "no", so you have to ask another question. My example asks what I wanted to know, not whether the other person can advise me.

Comment: See: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv239.shtml

Comment: @user067531 the examples you linked are interesting, but the situation here is about asking someone who works in a store for directions. Here, it's their job, not like they are doing you a favour, or you are asking for something extreme. IMO "can you tell me..."  or "could you help me" is mealy-mouthed.

Comment: You are in a shop(UK)/store(US). You find a salesperson. Despite @WeatherVane, I believe that if you say 'Where are the [tomatoes]?' to that person you will get a significantly less pleasing response than if you asked 'Could you tell me where the [tomatoes] are?'.

Comment: For politeness try "would you"...

Comment: @JeremyC, "Where are the [tomatoes]?" is neither what the OP asks, nor what I proposed in the first comment.

Comment: Hi Amy. In the UK "could" is considered more polite than "can". "Could you tell me where I'd find the mouthwash" is pretty standard. For maximum politeness you act a bit forlorn: "Excuse me. I wonder if you could help me. I'm looking for the mouthwash." But in my local shops, raising the eyebrows and saying, "Mouthwash, mate?" (or if it's a woman: "Mouthwash, love?") would be perfectly acceptable, especially if they were busy.